# Translating C# RSACryptoServiceProvider into JAVA Code

Tags: c#, java, security, encryption, rsa

I was given this C# code written by the web service team that exposes some web service that I'm planning to consume. My password needs to be encrypted with this code so that the web service knows how to decrypt it on their end.

```
using(RSACryptoServiceProvider rsa = new RSACryptoServiceProvider())
{
    rsa.FromXmlString(publicKey);
    byte[] plainBytes = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(clearText);
    byte[] encryptedBytes = rsa.Encrypt(plainBytes, false);
    return Convert.ToBase64String(encryptedBytes);
}
```

I'm using Java to consume this web service and right now, I'm having problem translating that #C code into Java code because that web service can't decrypt my password properly.

Here's my current failed attempt:-

```
// my clear text password
String clearTextPassword = "XXXXX";

// these values are provided by the web service team
String modulusString = "...";
String publicExponentString = "...";

BigInteger modulus = new BigInteger(1, Base64.decodeBase64(modulusString.getBytes("UTF-8")));
BigInteger publicExponent = new BigInteger(1, Base64.decodeBase64(publicExponentString.getBytes("UTF-8")));

KeyFactory keyFactory = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");

RSAPublicKeySpec publicKeySpec = new RSAPublicKeySpec(modulus, publicExponent);
PublicKey publicKey = keyFactory.generatePublic(publicKeySpec);

Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA/ECB/NoPadding");
cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, publicKey);

String encodedEncryptedPassword = new String(Base64.encodeBase64(cipher.doFinal(clearTextPassword.getBytes("UTF-8"))));
```

What did I do wrong? Thanks much.

**2013-08-07 - UPDATE**

I was reading [this website](http://stephenhirst.wordpress.com/2011/09/18/load-rsa-keys-from-modulus-and-exponent-in-java/) and I realized that my modulus value and public exponent value are not in Hex. So, I modified my code a little bit and tried with `RSA/ECB/PKCS1PADDING` as mentioned by @Dev.

```
// my clear text password
String clearTextPassword = "XXXXX";

// these are the actual values I get from the web service team
String modulusString = "hm2oRCtP6usJKYpq7o1K20uUuL11j5xRrbV4FCQhn/JeXLT21laKK9901P69YUS3bLo64x8G1PkCfRtjbbZCIaa1Ci/BCQX8nF2kZVfrPyzcmeAkq4wsDthuZ+jPInknzUI3TQPAzdj6gim97E731i6WP0MHFqW6ODeQ6Dsp8pc=";
String publicExponentString = "AQAB";

Base64 base64Encoder = new Base64();

String modulusHex = new String(Hex.encodeHex(modulusString.getBytes("UTF-8")));
String publicExponentHex = new String(Hex.encodeHex(publicExponentString.getBytes("UTF-8")));

BigInteger modulus = new BigInteger(modulusHex, 16);
BigInteger publicExponent = new BigInteger(publicExponentHex);

KeyFactory keyFactory = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");

RSAPublicKeySpec publicKeySpec = new RSAPublicKeySpec(modulus, publicExponent);
PublicKey publicKey = keyFactory.generatePublic(publicKeySpec);

Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA/ECB/PKCS1PADDING");
cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, publicKey);

String encodedEncryptedPassword = new String(base64Encoder.encode(cipher.doFinal(clearTextPassword.getBytes("UTF-8"))));
```

When I hit the webservice, I'm getting this error: **"The data to be decrypted exceeds the maximum for this modulus of 128 bytes."** It seems like the clear text password is still not encrypted properly.

Any help or suggestion is greatly appreciated. Thanks.

**2013-08-09 - SOLUTION**

I posted my final working solution below.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Found the solution.

```
String modulusString = "hm2oRCtP6usJKYpq7o1K20uUuL11j5xRrbV4FCQhn/JeXLT21laKK9901P69YUS3bLo64x8G1PkCfRtjbbZCIaa1Ci/BCQX8nF2kZVfrPyzcmeAkq4wsDthuZ+jPInknzUI3TQPAzdj6gim97E731i6WP0MHFqW6ODeQ6Dsp8pc=";
String publicExponentString = "AQAB";

byte[] modulusBytes = Base64.decodeBase64(modulusString);
byte[] exponentBytes = Base64.decodeBase64(publicExponentString);
BigInteger modulus = new BigInteger(1, modulusBytes);
BigInteger publicExponent = new BigInteger(1, exponentBytes);

RSAPublicKeySpec rsaPubKey = new RSAPublicKeySpec(modulus, publicExponent);
KeyFactory fact = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
PublicKey pubKey = fact.generatePublic(rsaPubKey);
Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA/ECB/PKCS1PADDING");
cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, pubKey);

byte[] plainBytes = clearTextPassword.getBytes("UTF-16LE");
byte[] cipherData = cipher.doFinal(plainBytes);
String encryptedStringBase64 = Base64.encodeBase64String(cipherData);
```

Comment: I had a feeling this would end up being a login protocol issue instead of the cipher. We'd covered just about everything else. Glad you figured it out.

Comment: When I see `Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(String)` I'm thinking `UTF-8`, not `UTF-16LE`, obviously and incorrect assumption, so good catch on your part.

Comment: Thanks for that - solved my problem. Looks like people in .NET often use Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes / Encoding.Unicode.GetString not realising it's not UTF-8.

Comment: If it works for you, consider upvoting it to ensure future users with similar problems notice this solution.

Comment: I cant see `modulusString` and `publicExponentString` in your c# code, may I know how its work in your c# code with these 2 value?

Comment: Do you have any idea about below error? java.lang.RuntimeException: error:03000068:bignum routines:OPENSSL_internal:CALLED_WITH_EVEN_MODULUS
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55743331/java-lang-runtimeexception-error03000068bignum-routinesopenssl-internalcall

Answer (score 2):

According to MSDN docs on [`RSACryptoServiceProvider.Encrypt`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.rsacryptoserviceprovider.encrypt.aspx), when the second argument is `false` the cipher uses PKCS#1 v1.5 padding. So right off the bat your cipher spec is incorrect.

Try `RSA/ECB/PKCS1PADDING` instead.

You are converting your key material to much in your second code example and you corrupted it which ends up making your cipher think you have more key material than you actually have and makes your message too long (which is triggering your error) as well as unintelligible to the decryption cipher on the other end. Convert directly to byte arrays and pass those to `BigInteger`.

```
String modulusString = "...";
String publicExponentString = "...";

byte[] mod = Base64.decodeBase64(modulusString);
byte[] e = Base64.decodeBase64(publicExponentString);

BigInteger modulus = new BigInteger(1, mod);
BigInteger publicExponent = new BigInteger(1, e);
```

Comment: I have tried that "RSA/ECB/PKCS1PADDING", and also "RSA" for the cipher. Both failed.

Comment: @limc Who's `Base64` class are you using?

Comment: I'm currently using Commons Codec. I initially used Spring's Codec, then I thought that would be the problem so I switched to Commons Codec... but they yield the same result.

Comment: @limc I would check to make sure the mod and exponent your getting in code matches what the C# code says the mod and exponent should be.

Comment: I updated my post. Please let me know if you spot any obvious problems from it. By the way, I'm going to upvote you for your helpful suggestion.

Comment: That gives me a login error from the web service. By the way, I'm not sure what Base64 class you use, but Commons Codec requires me to convert the string to byte array before passing into `Base64.decodeBase64()`.

Comment: @limc as of Commons Codec 1.4 see http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-codec/javadocs/api-release/org/apache/commons/codec/binary/Base64.html#decodeBase64(java.lang.String)

Comment: I updated my JAR version. I'm still getting the same "login" error.

Comment: @limc At this point I'd check the mod and exponent in both the .NET code and Java to make sure they are the same (the actual decimal number, not the Base64 encoded). For `BigInteger` you can just print it out, otherwise everything looks right to me assuming you're now passing the byte arrays directly to `BigInteger` constructor.

Answer (score 0):

Using `RSA/ECB/OAEPWithSHA-1AndMGF1Padding` seems to be the solution for this issue.

Don't forget these replacements.

Encoding to Base64
Use `System.Convert` to convert the input to Base64.

Replace + by - and / by _. Example: `Foo+bar/=== becomes Foo-bar_===.`

Replace any number of = at the end of the string, with an integer denoting how many they were. Example: Foo-bar_=== becomes Foo-bar_3.

Decoding from Base64
Replace the digit at the end of the string by the same number of = signs. Example: `Foo-bar_3 becomes Foo-bar_===.`

Replace - by + and _ by /. Example: `Foo-bar_=== becomes Foo+bar/===.`

Use System.Convert to decode the preprocessed input from Base64.