# What is the Java equivalent of this C# statement

Tags: c#, java, security, certificate

```
RSACryptoServiceProvider rsaCspPrivate = (RSACryptoServiceProvider)getCertificate().PrivateKey;
```

Comment: refer [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18089923/translating-c-sharp-rsacryptoserviceprovider-into-java-code)