# What is the Java equilant of this C# method RSACryptoServiceProvider.ExportCspBlob()

Tags: c#, java, security

We wrote a c# server app that muliple clients use a couple of years ago. Some use C++ and others use c# and others use python (They can all connect). A client is trying to use Java and just can't seem to get it to work.
The issue is the PublicKey representation.

In c# I don't send the raw `byte []` publicKey, I convert it to a blob using `RSACryptoServiceProvider.ExportCspBlob()`. So in the server app I simply use `rsaCSP.ImportCspBlob(publicKeyBlob)`;

**QUESTION**

How can I use Java to create a `RSACryptoServiceProvider.ExportCspBlob()` `byte[]` representation of the publicKey

### C# SERVER CODE

```
public static bool VerifySignature(byte[] hash, byte[] signature, byte[] publicKeyBlob)
    {
        RSACryptoServiceProvider rsaCSP = new RSACryptoServiceProvider();
        try
        {
            rsaCSP.ImportCspBlob(publicKeyBlob);
            bool res = rsaCSP.VerifyHash(hash, CryptoConfig.MapNameToOID("SHA1"), signature);
            return res;
        }
        catch
        {

            return false;
        }
        finally
        {
            if (rsaCSP != null)
                rsaCSP = null;
        } 
    }
```

### C# Client Code for public key that works

```
public static byte[] getPublicKeyBlob()
{
     RSACryptoServiceProvider rsaCspPublic = (RSACryptoServiceProvider)getCertificate()
                                                                .PublicKey.Key;
     return rsaCspPublic.ExportCspBlob(false);
}
```

### Java Client Code - In Progress (Currently gets the raw byte [] public key

```
public static byte[] getPublicKeyBlob(){ 
    try
    {  
        byte[] ba = keystore.getCertificate("le-f0b649ee-4e25-4973-a185-efd5bd587c54")
                                 .getPublicKey().getEncoded();    
        return ba;

    }catch(Exception e){

    }
    return null;
}
```

If anyone can assist me it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you read [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18146713/2970947)?

Comment: Hi, Yes I have seen it. But once I have the PublicKeySpec, how do I convert that to the byte[]? (ExportCspBlob)

Comment: Maybe its better to ask the following: What does the method RSACryptoServiceProvider.ExportCspBlob(false) actually do, so that I can write the java code to do the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems this is the way to do it (Only small issue is that Java puts one extra 00 byte which I just strip off in the server code)

```
public static byte[] getPublicKey(){ 
    try
    {                
        RSAPublicKey key = (RSAPublicKey)keystore.getCertificate("alias").getPublicKey();    
        return key.getModulus().toByteArray();

    }catch(Exception e){

    }
    return null;
}
```