# java.lang.RuntimeException: error:03000068:bignum routines:OPENSSL_internal:CALLED_WITH_EVEN_MODULUS

Tags: android, security, rsa, public-key-encryption

I want to implement RSA encryption with public and private key in the android. Implementation I have done is as below.

```
public static String enccriptData(String dataToEncrypt)
{
    try {
        String publicExponentString = "AQAB";
        String PUBLIC_KEY = "BgIAAACkAABSU0ExAAQAAAEAAQBJGj09Gbyl7BS/8MytvjBUUfaktW984VHHW4lSI9y2OwaeOq4qqSD6IOHU9HL/QtwZ+wELq28eAOQSnr11hifMf6zWjIsCBHOEpLNJjL3wxjl7dUBEGMJOeZj2rmcf8v7lP/rpAtO/G8wKXhAIKLIFxcChkXwQKbQbHQ/FtX2bwg=="

        byte[] modulusBytes = Base64.decodeBase64(PUBLIC_KEY);
        byte[] exponentBytes = Base64.decodeBase64(publicExponentString);
        BigInteger modulus = new BigInteger(1, modulusBytes);
        BigInteger publicExponent = new BigInteger(1, exponentBytes);

        RSAPublicKeySpec rsaPubKey = new RSAPublicKeySpec(modulus, publicExponent);
        KeyFactory fact = null;
        fact = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");

        PublicKey pubKey = fact.generatePublic(rsaPubKey);
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA/ECB/PKCS1PADDING");
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, pubKey);

        String token = dataToEncrypt + ":" + String.valueOf(getCurrentDateTimeTicks());

        byte[] plainBytes = token.getBytes("UTF-16LE");
        byte[] cipherData = cipher.doFinal(plainBytes);
        String encryptedStringBase64 = Base64.encodeBase64String(cipherData);
        return encryptedStringBase64;
    }catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return null;
}

private static long getCurrentDateTimeTicks(){
    long TICKS_AT_EPOCH = 621355968000000000L;
    long tick = System.currentTimeMillis()*10000 + TICKS_AT_EPOCH;
    return tick;
}
```

This works fine when I run this code as a Java file. It encrypts the data as expected. But, when I use this code in the android application, it gives below error.

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: error:03000068:bignum routines:OPENSSL_internal:CALLED_WITH_EVEN_MODULUS
 at com.android.org.conscrypt.NativeCrypto.RSA_public_encrypt(Native Method)
 at com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLCipherRSA$DirectRSA.doCryptoOperation(OpenSSLCipherRSA.java:371)
 at com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLCipherRSA.engineDoFinal(OpenSSLCipherRSA.java:292)
 at javax.crypto.Cipher.doFinal(Cipher.java:1741)
```

Equivalent C# code is as below

```
public string GenerateToken()
{
    var completeToken = string.Format("{0}:{1}", _dataToEncrypt, DateTime.UtcNow.Ticks);
    var encryptedToken = EncryptionHelper.Encrypt(_publicKey, completeToken);
    var token = Convert.ToBase64String(encryptedToken);
    return token;
}

public static byte[] Encrypt(string publicKey, string data)
{
    var cspParams = new CspParameters { ProviderType = 1 };
    var rsaProvider = new RSACryptoServiceProvider(cspParams);

    rsaProvider.ImportCspBlob(Convert.FromBase64String(publicKey));

    var plainBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(data);
    var encryptedBytes = rsaProvider.Encrypt(plainBytes, false);

    return encryptedBytes;
}
```

Ref link 
[Translating C# RSACryptoServiceProvider into JAVA Code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18089923/translating-c-sharp-rsacryptoserviceprovider-into-java-code)

Comment: The Java code looks good, but you excluded the modulus. Where does the RSA modulus come from? It seems to be not compliant to the requirements for RSA which causes this error.

Comment: In fact, the C# code and the android code have little in common, let alone being equivalent. The formats of the public keys accepted by `ImportCSPBlob()` in .NET and the BigInteger constructor in Java are utterly incompatible.

Comment: @Robert, I am provided only public key which I'm using as a modulus. This is working fine with Java code but issue is only with the android app

Comment: @Amit The public key contains the modulus, but it is not the modulus! You need to parse the public key and extract the modulus and the exponent from it. Ask the person you got the key from which format it is because the data is not ASN.1.

Comment: @Robert, Thanks for your feedback. I'll ask the concern person for the same

Comment: @Robert, I got the modulus now and it works now. But, there is one strange behavior. When I generate the token using java compiler, generated token works but when I run the code on Android, generated code can not be verified from the server. Do you have any idea?