# java.security.spec.InvalidKeySpecException: java.lang.RuntimeException: error:0c0000b9:ASN.1 encoding routines:OPENSSL_internal:WRONG_TAG

Tags: java, android, rsa, public-key

I want to convert String to RSAPublicKey in android. I have tried with below code but it gives exception. I want to use this key in extracting the modulus and exponent from the key.

```
  String PUBLIC_KEY = "BgIAAACkAABSU0ExAAQAAAEAAQBJGj09Gbyl7BS/8MytvjBUUfaktW984VHHW4lSI9y2OwaeOq4qqSD6IOHU9HL/QtwZ+wELq28eAOQSnr11hifMf6zWjIsCBHOEpLNJjL3wxjl7dUBEGMJOeZj2rmcf8v7lP/rpAtO/G8wKXhAIKLIFxcChkXwQKbQbHQ/FtX2bwg==";


  byte[] keyBytes = DatatypeConverter.parseBase64Binary(PUBLIC_KEY);
  X509EncodedKeySpec keySpec = new X509EncodedKeySpec(keyBytes);
  KeyFactory keyFactory = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
  PublicKey pubKey = keyFactory.generatePublic(keySpec);
```

*Exception*

```
java.security.spec.InvalidKeySpecException: java.lang.RuntimeException: error:0c0000b9:ASN.1 encoding routines:OPENSSL_internal:WRONG_TAG
at com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLKey.getPublicKey(OpenSSLKey.java:295)
at com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLRSAKeyFactory.engineGeneratePublic(OpenSSLRSAKeyFactory.java:47)
at java.security.KeyFactory.generatePublic(KeyFactory.java:357)

Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: error:0c0000b9:ASN.1 encoding routines:OPENSSL_internal:WRONG_TAG
at com.android.org.conscrypt.NativeCrypto.d2i_PUBKEY(Native Method)
at com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLKey.getPublicKey(OpenSSLKey.java:293)
... 20 more

java.lang.RuntimeException: error:03000070:bignum routines:OPENSSL_internal:NO_INVERSE
at com.android.org.conscrypt.NativeCrypto.RSA_public_encrypt(Native Method)
at com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLCipherRSA.engineDoFinal(OpenSSLCipherRSA.java:268)
at javax.crypto.Cipher.doFinal(Cipher.java:2056)
```

Comment: The key is still the same, and therefore the solution is the same, too. Ask the person you got the key from which format it is. Possible duplicate of [java.lang.RuntimeException: error:03000068:bignum routines:OPENSSL\_internal:CALLED\_WITH\_EVEN\_MODULUS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55743331/java-lang-runtimeexception-error03000068bignum-routinesopenssl-internalcall)

Comment: In this question, I want to extract modulus and exponent from the Public key. It can working properly when I run the code in the C#

Comment: If you have working c# code that is able to load the public key you should post it (edit your question and add it). Transferring c# to Java is much simpler than reverse-engineering an existing public key.